# "Open With" works in file explorer, but not through CLI

Tags: command-line, filemanager

I have installed `tuxguitar` which can open `.gp3` files when I double click on them, in the file explorer. This works perfectly fine.

I need to script the opening of sequential `.gp3` files through `tuxguitar` but when I type in the terminal :

```
/opt/tuxguitar/tuxguitar.sh "sample.gp3"
```

Then `tuxguitar` opens empty, instead of with the file I specified.

How can I see which exact command the GUI is calling so it opens `tuxguitar` with the file I clicked, pre-opened ?

EDIT : The `.desktop` entry is

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TuxGuitar
GenericName=TuxGuitar
Comment=TuxGuitar
Type=Application
MimeType=audio/x-tuxguitar;audio/x-gtp;audio/x-ptb
Categories=Application;AudioVideo;
Exec=/opt/tuxguitar/tuxguitar.sh %F
Icon=/opt/tuxguitar/share/skins/Oxygen/icon-96x96.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the syntax was correct, but for the specific case of `tuxguitar`, the complete file to the `.gp3` must be specified.

```
/opt/tuxguitar/tuxguitar.sh "/home/user/full_path/sample.gp3"
```